# C++/CLI CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Wrapper' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build, c++-cli

I am encountering an issue that seems identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659888/c-cli-dll-namespace-not-found-in-msvs).

I have a VS 2008 solution that includes, among other things:
(names changed for simplicity)

- DLL A: A native C++, business logic DLL
- DLL B: A C++/CLI wrapper for DLL A with a namespace of "Wrapper"
- EXE: A C# WinForms GUI EXE project that (references DLL B)

When I build the EXE, VS gives me an error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Wrapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However:

- There are no other errors or warnings reported
- All references in the EXE project seem to resolve properly
- DLL A and DLL B both build without errors or warnings
- [DLL A includes both .h header and .cpp files (that simply include the .h header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619752/c-cli-dll-namespace-not-found-in-msvs-c-sharp-project-successfully-reproducab)
- I can traverse the 'Wrapper' namespace in the object browser without issues

The first linked question mentions something about a "duplicate definition of a compiler symbol", but I'm not sure what to look for in that sense.

Any ideas for what to try?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the DLL B project from the EXE project? (You said all references resolve, but you didn't enumerate 'all'.)

Comment: @DavidYaw I figured it out - please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out.

Some more background: before building, the entire solution is created using CMake. I use CMake to make some edits to the csproj file for the EXE to point it to the correct references, including DLL B.

Whenever I run CMake, the statically defined GUID for DLL B in the ProjectReference node of the csproj file gets out of sync with the newly generated GUID for the vcproj that outputs DLL B. This GUID mismatch causes DLL B not to be referenced *at build time*, even though it shows up in the list of references and there are no related warnings or errors.

The way I discovered this was by looking at the build output. In the call to csc.exe, there was no '/reference' entry for DLL B.

Now I need to find a way to keep these GUIDs in sync!

Comment: @Kohnaz So how did you keep these GUID's in sync. Can you post the updated answer ?

Comment: @Versatile Luckily I somewhat documented this in a related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432733/931528), because my memory is quite hazy on this. There may well be better supported options nowadays with CMake + .NET.