# How can I generate a GUID in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I need to generate GUIDS in CMake to define unique identifiers in some custom configuration files. How can I use CMake to generate GUIDs?

Comment: Could you check if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415007/ is not a duplicate ? Not sure...

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to create unique identifiers in CMake (see [`string()`  Generation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/string.html#generation)).

E.g. `string(TIMESTAMP ...)`, `string(RANDOM ...)` or `string(UUID ...)`:

> ```
> string(UUID <output variable> NAMESPACE <namespace> NAME <name>
>    TYPE <MD5|SHA1> [UPPER])
> ```
>
> Create a univerally unique identifier (aka GUID) as per RFC4122

Examples from CMake's `string()` Unit Test [Uuid.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/RunCMake/string/Uuid.cmake):

> ```
> set(UUID_DNS_NAMESPACE 6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8)
> string(
>     UUID WWW_EXAMPLE_COM_MD5_UUID 
>     NAMESPACE ${UUID_DNS_NAMESPACE} 
>     NAME "www.example.com" 
>     TYPE MD5
> )
> string(
>     UUID WWW_EXAMPLE_COM_SHA1_UUID 
>     NAMESPACE ${UUID_DNS_NAMESPACE} 
>     NAME "www.example.com" 
>     TYPE SHA1 UPPER
> )
> ```